# How to snap to grid when dragging?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

By default when you drag a control (Label, TextBox, etc.) beside another control, it forces the control you're placing into alignment with the other control you just dragged.

I disabled that somehow by accident and now I have no clue how to re-enable it.

I have already tried changing everything on the page with no results, including after closing the designer and re-opening it for every single change I made.

[image: Non]

Comment: Solution: do NOT use the VS designer. WPF is not intended for drag and drop Developers, and the designer produces crappy XAML. Learn XAML and code it yourself.

Comment: I use the designer as more of a convenience thing (Only for projects that i will be using for myself), Mostly because it's faster to drag 10 controls on to a form and immediately start writing code for them, rather than type out the code for 10 controls and type the margins manually

Comment: Again: Learn XAML. Margins are not the correct way to layout an application. This is not winforms.

Comment: Ahh, Margins are a necessity When designing XAML. (even when using actual XAML code and not the designer), If you use a Canvas or some other grid that enables 'Absolute Positioning' using top / left / right / bottom you become unable to make use of a 'ViewBox' (Basically makes the WPF form re-sizable so that the elements will also resize).  Either way, This is irrelevant to my question and/or the reasoning of using the designer (speed).

Comment: PFFF... ok. It makes no sense to discuss layout with a drag and drop mentality... I was not talking about canvas. I was talking about WPF Layout, which has nothing to do with aboslute positioning. This is not winforms

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Fourth button from the left, bottom left of the designer window.

Comment: That looks extremely familiar!, but I don't have that on my window (even after resetting window layout) you can see my window in the picture

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to disable or enable that panel. Since I use VS2012, however, my default layout could be different.

Comment: lol, Usually resetting window layout brings me my controls back <_<